# How can I merge two dataframes of different row lengths based on a common column

Tags: python, dataframe, merge

I have two dataframes of different lengths and i want to join them together based on a common value in a specific column. I want the numbers column to be summed if the Ticker column matches. for example I want a new column and the value for EMBR3 BZ to be 2967205158 (2967200592 + 4566) while the row for ticker ASURB MM to be kept at 3356205474 as it is not present in df2.

to add to this i also have columns after the number column in both dataframes which are not shown below because there are too many columns and i dont want to lose them in my final output. if i use pd.merge i lose the columns after Number in df1. im really struggling with this and would appreciate if someone could help me thanks!

```
df1 

Ticker        Number
EMBR3 BZ    2967200592
LREN3 BZ    7655250160
ASURB MM    3356205474
ISA         2095646662
DFD         6765767657
L65N3 BZ    765545664

df2

Ticker        Number
EMBR3 BZ    4566
LREN3 BZ    3776
ISA         46575

output 

Ticker        Number            New Number
EMBR3 BZ    2967200592         2967205158
LREN3 BZ    7655250160         7655253936
ASURB MM    3356205474         3356205474
ISA         2095646662         2095693237
DFD         6765767657         6765767657           
L65N3 BZ    765545664          765545664
```

Comment: You are looking for .merge()  In this case you can do what's known as a left merge (left join) and.  Any values not in df2 will return null for the new number column which you will need to fill in another operation.

Comment: thanks but this doesnt actually join all the values for example it joins EMBR3 but misses ISA. I believe its because its not using the ticker column has a reference would I need to specify which column to merge on? ie ticker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`join` keeps the original index of a dataframe. That allows to build a simple Series with the correct index and use it directly in the original dataframe.

Here the new series will contain the values of `df2.Number`, 0 for the other rows and is casted to an int:

```
df1.join(df2.set_index('Ticker'),on='Ticker', lsuffix='_').Number.fillna(0).astype(int)
```

We can then use it to add a new column to the first dataframe:

```
df1['New Number'] = df1['Number'] + df1.join(df2.set_index('Ticker'),on='Ticker',
                                             lsuffix='_').Number.fillna(0).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `fill_value`:

```
df1['New Number'] = df1.add(df2, axis='columns', fill_value=0)
```

Comment: If you provide the code to create the dataframes I can try and refine the expression.